# date alternative in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT DATE(mbTimestamp_dt) As datefield1
```

The above DATE function works fine in MySQL 5.5 however, it doesn't work in SQL Server 2008.

Here mbTimestamp_dt is in the following format : 2014-01-13 16:53:44

What is the alternative for using DATE function in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function in MySQL is documented to

> Extract the date part of a date or datetime expression

In SQL Server 2008+ you can use [CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
SELECT CAST(mbTimestamp_dt AS DATE) As datefield1
```

to do the same.

The string format `2014-01-13 16:53:44` is not ambiguous when using the newer date/time datatypes.